# Why Base64 encoded image is not showing without trimming?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a img field whose value is base64 encoded. I checked the value in a decoder and it is bmp. when i put the value like  it is not showing. I saw an example where the encoded string is trimmed with (base64 encoded string).substr(104). Image start rendering. I did not get a proper reason what is the reason behind trimming it.. Please suggest me with the exact reason. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code in question, the encoded string, and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If it works after trimming first 104 characters, then if 1 character is 6 bits of information, then `104 characters == 624 bits == 78 bytes`. If it works after trimming, then those first 78 bytes are redundant, they are probably some information, ex. a header.

It would be a lot harder if you'd have to remove number of bytes non-evenly divisible by 3. As 78 is evenly divisible by 3, it corresponds exactly to 104 characters.